# Why is the browser default focus style not applied when focusing after a click event?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, focus

I have a control that appears after pressing a button. When it appears, there are some checkboxes. And I want to focus on the first checkbox.

This works properly when "clicking" the button with the enter key after tabbing to it.
It also works if you tab to the button and then click with the mouse. 
It doesn't work properly if you click on the button without it having focus first.

See the below for a cut down of what I have.

```js
$('button.goBtn').on("click", () => {
  let c = $('.inputs input:checkbox:first');
  c.focus();
});
```

```css
.inputs ul {
   list-style-type: none;
}

.inputs label {
   margin-left:10px;
}
button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Stop</button>
<button type="button" class="goBtn">Go</button>
<div class="inputs">
 <ul>
     <li><input type="checkbox" id="c1" value="1"/><label for="c1">Checkbox 1</label></li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" id="c2" value="2"/><label for="c2">Checkbox 2</label></li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" id="c3" value="3"/><label for="c3">Checkbox 3</label></li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" id="c4" value="4"/><label for="c4">Checkbox 4</label></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The first checkbox is actually focused as you can see by pressing the space bar, but it is not "visually" focused.

You can also see this by including an `input:focus` style, but I don't want to do this.

Comment: I added chrome to the tag-list. This issue is not happening in firefox.

Comment: I found it doesn't properly work in firefox either - it's just weirder. If you first get it working, then it always works on the page.

Comment: Fwiw, I didn't test in a test-web-page, just the code snippet above. I might try it now.

Comment: Hang on, clicking Go refreshes the page, so everything resets, as it's supposed to (no focus). If this is not what happens when clicking Go, plz update with details.

Comment: The page shouldn't refresh. It's probably because I forgot to include the type of the button. I have edited the snippet to include type="button"

Comment: That does it. I see what you mean now about FF being weirder. My guess now is that you won't get around this without additional css/js/etc; seems like a browser difference. Maybe plain js would work differently.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need JS / Jquery for that to work (what you want can be achieved by
input control itself), so the first check box shall be:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" value="1" autofocus/>
```

Its working in chrome and IE

Comment: That might work if there was nothing else on the page that could be focused. There are many more items on the real life page though.